# How to check if the collection is empty in NHibernate (HQL)?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I have a following HQL query:
    SELECT s.id
          FROM
              stack s
    WHERE
          s.category is not empty

Basically, s.category is a one-to-many join to another table (Category).
I need to check whether the collection is empty or no. I can do it in c# code (just run through all of the Stacks and check if Stack.category.count > 0. Is there any HQL way to do so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this syntax works here:

```
from stack s where exists elements(s.category)
```