# HQL Query to check if size of collection is 0 or empty

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I try to generate a HQL query that include user with a empty appoinment collections(mapped by OneToMany):

```
SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.appointments uas WHERE u.status = 1 AND (uas.time.end < :date OR size(uas) = 0)
```

I tries it on several manners (`NOT EXIST ELEMENT(), IS NULL`)
also see: [How to check if the collection is empty in NHibernate (HQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105011/how-to-check-if-the-collection-is-empty-in-nhibernate-hql/1105057#1105057) (This doesn't work for me)

but still not the result I want to see or some error in HQL or SQL SERVER

**Note:**

the query without the JOIN works:

```
"FROM User u WHERE u.status = 1 AND size(u.appointments) = 0"
```

**Solved**

Another JOIN solved the problem:

```
SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN u.appointments pas1 LEFT JOIN pas1.slot t WHERE u.status = 1 AND t.end <= :date1 OR t.end IS NULL ORDER BY u.name asc
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Using `IS EMPTY` should work (I would favor a JPQL syntax):

```
SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.status = 1 AND u.appointments IS EMPTY
```

If it doesn't, please show the generated SQL.

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [14.10. Expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)
- JPA 1.0 specification

  - Section 4.6.11 "Empty Collection Comparison Expressions"

Comment: unfortunately ' "FROM User u JOIN u.appointments uas WHERE u.status = 1 AND uas is empty" ' doesn't work. It gives me no users. And there are a lot of users without appointments

Comment: mm your suggestion works but i needed that JOIN. I'm looking for the method to use the size or is empty in combination with the Join, Thx for your support

Comment: @michel Why do you need the join? Your query with the JOIN will only return users with matching values in the join condition (i.e. users *with* appointments).

Comment: @Pascal
I need it because I need all users with appointments not older than 10 days for example and with no appointments

Comment: @michel You might need a LEFT JOIN then, not an INNER JOIN. Your current query (without the condition on the appointments size) is not doing what you want.

Comment: @Pascal
something like this:
--> SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN u.appointments uas WHERE u.status = 1 AND (uas.slot.end <= :date1 OR size(u.appointments) = 0 ) ORDER BY u.name asc <--  This gives me only the users with appointments and --> SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN u.appointments uas WHERE u.status = 1 AND (uas.slot.end <= :date1 OR size(uas) = 0 ) ORDER BY u.name asc <-- gives me the error: "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -5" BTW: when using "IS EMPTY" no STringIndexOutOfBoundsException but only 2 users instead of thousands

Comment: @michel It's hard to discuss this in a comment box but do you agree that `SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.appointments uas WHERE u.status = 1` won't return any record without appointments (and is thus not what you want?)

Comment: `BTW: when using "IS EMPTY" no STringIndexOutOfBoundsException but only 2 users instead of thousands` Show the generated SQL.

Comment: @Pascal I double agree with you, difficult to discus the problem here and the SELECT with the INNER JOIN doesn't give the correct result, But how can I solve this? Do I need an IN query?

Comment: @michel It might help to see the generated SQL for analysis. But somehow, this is a different question. Maybe opening another question for this purpose would be better.

Comment: I Solved the problem. I need another JOIN in my HQL query: 
SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN u.appointments pas1 LEFT JOIN pas1.slot t WHERE u.status = 1 AND t.end <= :date1 OR t.end IS NULL ORDER BY u.name asc Thanks for helping with the Solution. The suggestion LEFT JOIN helps me a lot. THX

Comment: @michel Well, glad this little discussion helped to find the solution. Well done.

Answer (score 15):

Have you taken a look at your generated SQL? Your method works fine here:

```
// Hibernate query:
const string hql = "from User u where u.Id = 101 and size(u.Appointments) = 0";


// Generates this working SQL:
select user0_.Id    as Id20_,
       user0_.Name as Name2_20_
from   User user0_
where  user0_.Id = 101
       and (select count(appointment1_.Id_Solicitud)
            from   Appointment appointment1_
            where  user0_.Id = appointment1_.Id_User) = 0
```

Answer (score 9):

```
// Hibernate query:
const string hql = "from User u where u.Id = 101 and size(u.Appointments) = 0";
```

Comment: A little explanation would make your answer even better. :)

Comment: where size() = 0 worked for me, where IS Empty was Not Supported.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following query will work. The trick is using the LEFT join.

```
SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN u.appointments uas 
WHERE u.status = 1 AND 
(uas.time.end < :date OR size(u.appointments) = 0)
```