# How to query this one to one relationship with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the next ER structure:

[image]

And my entities are like this:

Event.java

```
public class Event implements Serializable {

.. many attributes here

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "evento",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
     private Quiz quiz;

many getters & setters here ...

}
```

Quiz.java

```
public class Quiz implements Serializable {

    @JoinColumn(name = "evento",referencedColumnName = "id")
    @OneToOne
    private Evento evento;
}
```

I want to fetch every event without quiz, so my query is this:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Evento AS e WHERE e.encuesta IS NULL",Evento.class);
```

But I'm getting an empty list

I'm using hibernate for the persistence.

Somebody can help me :) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `IS EMPTY` clause:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Evento AS e WHERE e.encuesta IS EMPTY",Evento.class);
```

See this:

[HQL Query to check if size of collection is 0 or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760711/hql-query-to-check-if-size-of-collection-is-0-or-empty)