# Is there anyway I can use JPQL's SIZE function for binding parameters in a WHERE clause?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

Is there anyway I can use JPQL's `SIZE` function for binding variables in a `WHERE` clause?

Something like this:

```
and (size(:distributor_ids) = 0 or d.id in (:distributor_ids))
```

Hibernate throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unexpected expression ? found for collection function size
```

My query is very big, but this AND clause fairly simple: if the list is empty, then retrieve everything; if the list is not empty, then retrieve all the rows that met `d.id IN (:distributor_ids)`.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to return everything in case argument is empty or only the items with ids matching the argument.

As it mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54041299/hql-check-list-size-passed-in-param) this is not possible for now, though you might be interested in suggested [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61973048/12473843).

> Is there anyway to achieve this?

Personally I would do it on Java side within service class calling `SomeRepository.findAll()` for empty  collection and `SomeRepository.findAllByIds()` for the opposite.

Comment: Perhaps I made it too simple. My query is really big, but this AND clause is very simple.

Comment: @MatheusCirillo if `d` in your query is an alias of joined entity then the workaround within the second link in my answer might be useful for you.

Comment: I appreciate your help! As I'm using Spring JPA Repositories, I came with the solution of using SpeL: `and (:#{#distributor_ids == null} = true or d.id in (:distributor_ids))`. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Nice! Alternatively this could be implemented with `*RepositoryImpl` class

Comment: Btw, I think you should share your solution as the answer for this question, as quite a few people facing similar issues

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's very simple to do this. Only add the condition to your query if the list is non empty. With JPA Criteria, you can do something like this:

```
List<Integer> distributorIds = ...
if (!distributorIds.isEmpty()) {
    criteriaQuery.where(root.get("id").in(distributorIds));
}
```

In a bigger query, you can collect individual `Predicate` objects in a list and finally set a conjunction of them, created via `CriteriaBuilder.and()` as where clause predicate.