# SQLSyntaxErrorException in Hibernate Where clause

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to use the Where clause to filter out empty entities.

i.e.

```
 @Where(clause = "size(userTracking) > 0 OR size(userResults) > 0")
```

In

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@Where(clause = "size(userTracking) > 0 OR size(userResults) > 0")
private List<UserSession> userSessions  = new ArrayList<UserSession>();
```

And in UserSessions

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_session_id", updatable = false)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<UserResult> userResults = new ArrayList<UserResult>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_session_id", updatable = false)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<UserTracking> userTracking = new ArrayList<UserTracking>();
```

However the error I'm getting is

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: FUNCTION database.size does not exist
```

Is it possible to use the @Where clause in this way?

It's not a duplicate of

[HQL Query to check if size of collection is 0 or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760711/hql-query-to-check-if-size-of-collection-is-0-or-empty)

I'm explicity saying that .size() doesn't work here.

.size doesn't work either

```
Java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'userTracking.size' in 'where clause'
```

I've also tried 'is not empty' however

```
 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'usersessio0_.EMPTY OR usersessio0_.userResults IS usersessio0_.EMPTY) and users' at line 1
```

Comment: Thanks I've been trying that - Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'usersessio0_.EMPTY OR usersessio0_.userResults IS usersessio0_.EMPTY)  and users' at line 1

Comment: Thanks. You marked it as a duplicate when I explicitly said that answer is not working. But thanks for highlighting the difference in the syntax. X is not empty isn't working either, see the above comment.  I'll try .size

Comment: `@Where` defines a *SQL* WHERE clause, not an HQL WHERE clause, so you'd need to write `@Where(clause = "user_session_id IN ( SELECT xxx FROM UserTracking ) OR user_session_id IN ( SELECT xxx FROM UserResult )")`

Answer (score 1):

`@Where` defines a *SQL* WHERE clause, not an HQL WHERE clause, so you'd need to write:

```
@Where(clause = "user_session_id IN ( SELECT xxx FROM UserTracking ) OR user_session_id IN ( SELECT xxx FROM UserResult )")
```

where `xxx` is whatever those columns are named.